# and condition in a if statement (as part of a for-loop) not working

Tags: python

I'm a bit stuck on my code. I'm trying to run a piece of code where the user is prompted to provide an input (i.e. a state in the US). The code then loops through a list of states in a list called `states_list`, and if there is a match it goes on to add that to a list called `correct_states`, and then creates a turtle object (etc.) as you will see when that condition is met. However, I'm also trying to add in some validation logic where if the initial input provided by the user has already been provided (i.e. is already in the `correct_states` list) then it should break the loop.

```
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:

    correct_states = []
    answer_state = screen.textinput(title=(f"{score}/50 states correct "), prompt="Enter a state of the US:").title()
    print(answer_state)

    for state in states_list:
        if answer_state == state and answer_state not in correct_states:
            correct_states.append(answer_state)
            score += 1
            print("Good")
            state_details = states_data[states_data["state"] == state]
            state_details_list = state_details.values.tolist()
            state_x_coor = state_details_list[0][1]
            state_y_coor = state_details_list[0][2]
            print(state_x_coor, state_y_coor)
            state_label = turtle.Turtle()
            state_label.penup()
            state_label.hideturtle()
            state_label.goto(state_x_coor, state_y_coor)
            state_label.write(arg=(f"{answer_state}"), align='center', font=('Bahnschrift', 9, 'normal'))

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the condition _works_, but not as you _expect_. What logging or debugging have you done? Where is `states_list` defined? And why do you need a while loop? Notice that you are never actually breaking any loop

Comment: Not sure why you need the `for state in states_list` loop instead of just checking `if answer_state in states_list`.

Comment: @khelwood. I didn't know this was possible but will give it a go - thank you !

Comment: @OneCricketeer. The states_list is defined above the 'while game_is_on' . I haven't really done any debugging yet apart from trying different approaches but will try this soon. Thank you

Comment: Okay, well, with the code shown, `screen.mainloop()` will never run because the infinite loop, so it's not clear what turtle stuff you expect to be happening

Comment: i realised that the correct_states list needs to go outside of the while loop (DOH!!!).
It's moments like this where I remember why I signed up to learn this :)

Comment: thanks all !!!!